# Implementing OnClickListener in Activity yields no result

Tags: java, android

In my activity I'm trying to use  `onClick` instead of overriding the `onTouchEvent` method, when I implement `OnClickListener` and override the `onClick` method, I get no results. However, using `onTouchEvent` method and applying my logic there works just fine.

What can I do to use `onClick` in my activity?

```
public class PixelParticle extends View{

    private float locationX;
    private float locationY;
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;
    private Paint color;
    private Rect rect;
    private int paintcolor;


    public PixelParticle(Context context, float locationX, float locationY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int paintcolor) {
        super(context);

        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
        this.paintcolor = paintcolor;

        rect = new Rect();
        color = new Paint();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, sizeX, sizeY, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap,locationX -(resizedBitmap.getWidth() / 2) ,locationY - (resizedBitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);


    }




}
```

..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private int pixelColor;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //removes title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //sets view to full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            pixelColor = Color.RED;
            PixelParticle pp = new PixelParticle(this, x, y, 50, 50, pixelColor);
            setContentView(pp);


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        } 

}
```

When I comment out `onTouchEvent` and write the same code inside the `onClick`, nothing happens.

and the XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:onClick="onClick" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possibly your element is not clickable. but there could be a dozen other reasons. hard to tell, without code.

Comment: did you set the clickListener to your view, I mean the view.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: try setting the clickable property of that element to true in your xml file.

Comment: Post your code...without code it hard to say anything.

Comment: where did you set the `onClickListener`?

Comment: In the activity. `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {....}`.

Comment: So, you want to set the `onClickListener` for your whole layout?

Comment: Well, as you can see, when the code is inside `onTouchEvent` it draws the little android and I can then drag it across the screen if I move my finger, but I don't want that, I just want to click the screen and have the canvas draw it, I don't want the ability to drag. So I'm trying `onClick`

Comment: then please, post your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what kind of touch event has fired and use that to work out whether to redraw or not.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Do your drawing here..
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.